# Newbie python script, odometry

Tags: ros, navigation, odometry, tum-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was doing one online course where on page was special frame to run python script. My task in this exercise was to compute the odometry, velocities are given.

This script on page looks: http://snag.gy/NTJGz.jpg

Now I would like to do the same using ROS: there is nearly the same exercise but in ROS:

clear code looks: https://github.com/tum-vision/autonavx_ardrone/blob/master/ardrone_python/src/example1_odometry.py

There is information that I should add code from this online_course version to function callback, I try, but it doesn't work.

My code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#ROS
import rospy
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('ardrone_python')
from ardrone_autonomy.msg import Navdata
import numpy as np

def __init__(self):
    self.position = np.array([[0], [0]])


def rotation_to_world(self, yaw):
        from math import cos, sin
        return np.array([[cos(yaw), -sin(yaw)], [sin(yaw), cos(yaw)]])


def callback(self, t, dt, navdata):
        self.position = self.position + dt * np.dot(self.rotation_to_world(navdata.rotZ), np.array([[navdata.vx], [navdata.vy]]))      
        print("received odometry message: vx=%f vy=%f z=%f yaw=%f"%(navdata.vx,navdata.vy,navdata.altd,navdata.rotZ))
        print(self.position)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('example_node', anonymous=True)

    # subscribe to navdata (receive from quadrotor)
    rospy.Subscriber("/ardrone/navdata", Navdata, callback(self, t, dt, navdata))

    rospy.spin()
```

Please correct me, I am totally newbie to python.

Now I get message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "./example1_odometry.py", line 28, in rospy.Subscriber("/ardrone/navdata", Navdata, callback(self, t, dt, navdata)) NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/197149/newbie-python-script,-odometry/) by [green96](https://answers.ros.org/users/20466/green96/) on ROS Answers with karma: 115 on 2014-11-10

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained) about what self means in python.

The issue you're having is that the `callback`, `rotation` and `__init__` methods and the `position` variable were originally part of a class. You need to remove the `__init__` method, "declare" the `position` variable and remove all references to `self` from your code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

#ROS
import rospy
import roslib; roslib.load_manifest('ardrone_python')
from ardrone_autonomy.msg import Navdata
import numpy as np

position = np.array([[0], [0]])


def rotation_to_world(yaw):
        from math import cos, sin
        return np.array([[cos(yaw), -sin(yaw)], [sin(yaw), cos(yaw)]])


def callback(t, dt, navdata):
        position = position + dt * np.dot(rotation_to_world(navdata.rotZ), np.array([[navdata.vx], [navdata.vy]]))      
        print("received odometry message: vx=%f vy=%f z=%f yaw=%f"%(navdata.vx,navdata.vy,navdata.altd,navdata.rotZ))
        print(position)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node('example_node', anonymous=True)

    # subscribe to navdata (receive from quadrotor)
    rospy.Subscriber("/ardrone/navdata", Navdata, callback)

    rospy.spin()
```

I haven't tested if this code actually works, but it us just to give you an idea on how to solve your issue.

Hope it helps

---

Originally posted by [Gary Servin](https://answers.ros.org/users/10481/gary-servin/) with karma: 962 on 2014-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3